# Paketo Spring boot 3.0 jar issue

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graalvm, paketo

I'm currently migrating to Spring boot 3.0.
In the process, I'm looking into using the newly integrated Native support.

When using pack to build and publish my image, I get an error:

```
Executing native-image -H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC -jar /workspace 
Error: /workspace is a directory. (-jar requires a valid jarfile)
```

Apparently, the native-image buildpack is trying to use the folder instead of jar.
I'm using this command to try to build the image.

```
 pack -v build ghcr.io/kevinbos-cc/buildpacks-demo:latest \
          --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny \
          --path . \
          --env "BP_JVM_VERSION=17" \
          --env "BP_NATIVE_IMAGE=true" \
          --cache-image ghcr.io/kevinbos-cc/buildpacks-demo-paketo-cache-image:latest \
          --publish
```

I've tried to change the **paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image** version and to use **paketo-buildpacks/graalvm**.
Unfortently these changes had the same result.

When running the **./gradle bootBuildImage** the image is created just fine.
But I can't figure out how to reproduce this in the pack command.

Full stack trace can be found [here](https://github.com/kevinbos-cc/buildpacks-demo/actions/runs/3614189584/jobs/6090454868).

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're hitting an issue between Spring/Gradle & Buildpacks that is fairly common.

I think it was in Spring Boot 2.7, a setting was changed that causes Gradle builds, by default, to produce both a boot-ified and regular JAR file. By itself, this isn't a problem, but buildpacks need to handle multiple JAR files differently than a single JAR file, and some things like a native-image build still only work with single JAR files.

I know for sure that your build is producing two JAR files, as I can see in the output you linked. It says this:

> Restoring multiple artifacts

so that's a pretty good sign that you're hitting this issue.

The good news is that this is an easy fix. You just need to tell Gradle to only build the boot-ified JAR.

In your `build.gradle` set this:

```
jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

or `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = false
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/samples/blob/main/java/gradle/build.gradle#L11-L13) or [here for Kotlin](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/samples/blob/main/java/kotlin/build.gradle.kts#LL14-L16C2).

If that doesn't help, you may be hitting a bug. In that case, please open an [issue here and post a sample to reproduce](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/gradle).

Comment: That's indeed the problem! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Daniel's answer is the best solution IMO, but if changing the build file is not desirable then another option is to set `--env BP_GRADLE_BUILT_ARTIFACT=build/libs/[name of fat jar file].jar`. Using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin with `./gradle bootBuildImage` doesn't have this problem because the Spring Boot plugin has enough context to know that only the Boot fat jar should be sent to the Paketo builder.